# limit file type in admin custom module

Tags: magento2.3, adminhtml, custom, file-upload

Hi everybody how are you

I have a problem to limit the type of file that can be uploaded from the administrator panel in a custom module, I only need the type csv and xls

I try a class that extends from\Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\File But it does not work, I can upload any type of file

the field from system.xml are:

```
<field id="shipping_csv_upload" translate="label" type="Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\File" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" >
                <label>Upload csv</label>
                <backend_model>Ipinnovatech\Ordertoapi\Model\Config\Backend\CustomFileType</backend_model>
                <upload_dir config="system" scope_info="1" >upload</upload_dir>
```

and the class for custom file type is:

```
class CustomFileType extends \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\File
{
    /**
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function getAllowedExtensions() {
        return ['csv', 'xls'];
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you allow only CSV and xls file upload then you can add the method beforeSave into the CustomFileType.php and write the exception based on your file type.**

```
class CustomFileType extends \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\File
{
    /**
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function getAllowedExtensions() {
        return ['csv', 'xls'];
    }

    public function beforeSave()
    {
        $file = $this->getFileData();
        if (!empty($file)) {
            try {
                    //check the file type is csv or xls if not than throw exception error
                }
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('%1', $e->getMessage()));
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

**I hope this is helpful to you!! don't forget to Votes**

Comment: yes, this was useful to me, thanks